# Postgres ODBC: connection "actively refused"

Tags: windows, postgresql, networking, odbc, database-connection

I'm using SSH tunneling to connect from a Windows 7 machine to a remote Postgres database.

The tunnel works fine when I use pgAdmin to connect to the remote database.  However, I haven't managed to set up an ODBC DSN to connect to the remote database.

I'm creating a System DSN with the same server address/username/password/port/ssl mode as pgAdmin but when I click "Test" I get:  "Could not connect to server; No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

Any ideas on where to start debugging?  I've ruled out Windows Firewall and remote server configuration, since I *can* connect with the exact same information in pgAdmin.

**Edit**

The problem resolved itself after reinstalling Windows.

Comment: Do you have any traces (something in log file) on server side?

Comment: The server had no record of the connection.  Finally I wiped the machine (reinstalled Windows 7) and started over, and it worked. But it's unnerving since I have no idea when it could happen again...

Comment: to the OP, can you show how and where you put the tunnel info in the DSN with PostgreSQL ODBC driver... i am doing it the first time. Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

When debugging this the first thing to do is to start testing the PostgreSQL server with the psql command line utility.  This avoids issues of drivers etc to see what is actually going on.  Generally speaking my troubleshooting process is:

1. Can I ping the server?
2. Can I connect with psql?
3. When I test my connection via the control panel, does it work?

Now, assuming the problem is on #2, the first thing I would do is try disabling firewalls on both sides (they can be brought up and tuned after trying with both down).  This rules out misbehaving firewalls and if it shows this to be a problem then you have the answer on where to troubleshoot.

In my experience Windows firewall can cause all manner of problems.  I have even seen it block web pages *halfway through the web page.* I don't think you can rule out Windows Firewall based on the information you have provided.

If this happens again, the first things to do include disabling both any antivirus software and firewalls.

The other possibility would be a bad ODBC config (maybe port 5423 instead of 5432) or a badly installed DLL of some sort.  The latter may be fixed (or not) using `sfc /scannow` or reinstalling the odbc driver, or other actions.